# How can I filter to an array and choose a random Id from it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Good night folks.

I'm new to programming, less than 2 months, so I don't quite understand how to make this work. Here's exactly what I want to do:
I have this game I'm trying to make which needs to do a raffle between existing units that fit the condition "is alive" and have "is able to use the prize". To do that, I was told I needed to include an array with the unit Id for the units that can receive it, then filter them by "is alive" to choose from by a random generator. Thing is, I have no idea how to make this work. I've tried this code, but it does not work. Anyone has any idea why or how I should do it instead?

```
var rafflearray = []; // the array containing the units
if (root.getExternalData().isUnitRegistered() = true) {var character = root.getCurrentSession().getPlayerList().getData()}; // establish the character as a variable

if (var character.getAliveStatus = true ) {rafflearray.push(character)}; // checks his alive status and send him to the array

var chosen = rafflearray [Math.random()*chosenarray.lenght]; // to choose amongst them
chosen.addItem()
```

Thanks in advance for the attention!

Comment: Math.floor(Math.random() * chosenArray.length) - try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest going through Javascript Fundamentals ([*here section 1 & 2*](https://www.javascripttutorial.net)) before this project. However I hope this answer helps you

First of all you cannot use **var** inside **if** statements like

```js
 if(var character.getAliveStatus = true)
```

And you need to use `==` or `===` instead of `=` , like:

```js
if(isAlive === true){
    // Code to be executed
}
// the difference between '==' and '===' can be found in the docs mentioned below
```

see **Javascript Operators** from [here](https://www.javascripttutorial.net) on section 3

**var** is for declaring a variable which is not limited to its parent blocks [*see javascript scoping*](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-variable-scope/)

In your case I'm not sure if you have an array of players already or if you're trying to make one.

In the first situation, I suggest you use `Array.filter()` function which is a cool way. For example :

```js
// Assuming 'players' is the array of players in the game

// filtering out raffle worthy players
let raffle_worthy = players.filter(player => player.getAliveStatus === true); 

// Randomly choosing 1 person between the raffle worthy players
let chosen = raffle_worthy[Math.floor(Math.random * raffle_worthy.length)]
```

You may want to take a look at [Array.filter()](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-filter/) docs and also [Js Math](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_math.asp) has been used in the above example

On the other hand if you dont have an array of players and getting them one by one, I'm not really sure if I can understand the way you get users and what gathers them